# Hamiltonian acting on sum operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

I am following a derivation in a book. It is implementing a state $|{\psi}\rangle$ into the eigenvalue equation $\hat{H}|{\psi}\rangle=E|{\psi}\rangle$. The $|{\psi}\rangle$ term contains a $|{\phi}\rangle-\Sigma_n|{\chi_n}\rangle...$ and when is expanded it becomes $\hat{H}|{\phi}\rangle-\Sigma_{n} E_n|{\chi_n}\rangle...$.

Could someone explain why the Hamiltonian becomes $E_n$ when acting within the sigma operator?

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit more on the expanded line, but it looks like its just the eigenvalue of the n(th) state, i.e. the energy of the nth excited state of $\chi$ (look at the harmonic oscillator for example). This would mean that the sigma operator and the Hamiltonian commute. Do you have the form of the sigma operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems, the state $|\psi\rangle$ is a superposition of $|\phi\rangle$ and several eigenstates of the Hamiltonian:

$$
\hat{H}|\chi_n\rangle = E_n|\chi_n\rangle
$$

The sigma then just denotes the sum of the eigenstates. And since the Hamilton operator is linear, you can easily apply it to each element of the sum independently.

$$
\hat{H}|\psi\rangle = \hat{H}\left(|\phi\rangle - \Sigma_n|\chi_n\rangle\right)
= \hat{H}|\phi\rangle - \hat{H}\left(|\chi_1\rangle + |\chi_2\rangle + \dots \right)
$$
$$
= \hat{H}|\phi\rangle - \left(\hat{H}|\chi_1\rangle + \hat{H}|\chi_2\rangle + \cdots\right)
= \hat{H}|\phi\rangle - \left(E_1|\chi_1\rangle + E_2|\chi_2\rangle + \cdots\right)
$$
$$
 = \hat{H}|\phi\rangle - \Sigma_nE_n|\chi_n\rangle
$$